# How to find the length in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.friends = [
      { name: "Peter", age: 20 },
      { name: "Pablo", age: 55 },
      { name: "Linda", age: 20 },
      { name: "Marta", age: 37 },
      { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
      { name: "Markus", age: 32 }
    ];

});
```

age: 20 I want to find the number of those. I used **ng-if** for this, but what I do is I always finding the length of the index. can you help?

I have one more question. We want to write length into data-badge. 
`<ul ng-if="result.type=='mesh'" class="mdl-list__item-primary-content mdl-badge results-icon" data-badge={{len}}>`

I wrote but it was not.

Comment: Add your HTML ?

Comment: Can you please include the HTML code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter method of an array. I have added the code snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.friends = [
      { name: "Peter", age: 20 },
      { name: "Pablo", age: 55 },
      { name: "Linda", age: 20 },
      { name: "Marta", age: 37 },
      { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
      { name: "Markus", age: 32 }
    ];
    
    var len = $scope.friends.filter(function(friend){
       if( friend.age == 20 ){
           return friend;
       }
    }).length;
    
    console.log("length=" + len);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl"></div>
```

Here is a better approach using `$filter` service present into angularjs.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.friends = [
      { name: "Peter", age: 20 },
      { name: "Pablo", age: 55 },
      { name: "Linda", age: 20 },
      { name: "Marta", age: 37 },
      { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
      { name: "Markus", age: 32 }
    ];
    
    var len = $filter('filter')($scope.friends, {'age' : 20}).length;
    
    console.log("length=" + len);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">
```

Comment: I have one more question. We want to write **length** into data-badge.

<ul ng-if="result.type=='mesh'" class="mdl-list__item-primary-content mdl-badge results-icon" data-badge={{len}}> 

I wrote but it was not. @Kaustubh Khare

Comment: Write `$scope.len` instead of `var len`;

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a **filter**. There are many different ways you can apply it on your input. Here is one example, with a checkbox and a set value, e.g. `{'age':20}`, which you can change dynamically too:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.age = 20;
  $scope.c = true;
  $scope.friends = [
    { name: "Peter", age: 20 },
    { name: "Pablo", age: 55 },
    { name: "Linda", age: 20 },
    { name: "Marta", age: 37 },
    { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
    { name: "Markus", age: 32 }
  ];

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myctrl">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="c" /> <tt>age:{{age}}</tt>
    <br>
    <input type="range" name="range" ng-model="age" min="0" max="100">
    <hr>

    <div ng-repeat="f in filtered=(friends | filter: c ? {'age':age} : '')">
      {{f}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    Length: {{filtered.length}}

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```